# Multiple partial view rendering

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have three dropdownlist - Project, Sprint, Story.
Sprint dropdownlist will be binded on the basis of selected Project, Story dropdownlist will be binded on the basis of selected Sprint. On the basis of selected Story, i want to show a webgrid.

what i m doing is:
my Project dropdownlist is on the main view page, Sprint dropdownlist, and Story dropdownlist are two diferent partial views. When i select from Project, selected value is taken in jquery and passed to controller as:

```
$('#Project').change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedVal = $("#Project").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Task/BindSprintList",
        data: { projectTitle: selectedVal },
        type: 'Get',
        success: function (result) { 
                $('#ViewGrid').html(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("something seems wrong");
        }
    });
});
```

Now Sprint Dropdown list appears. When i select from Sprint, selected value is taken in jquery and passed to controller as:

```
$('#Sprint').change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedProjectVal = $("#Project").val();
    var selectedSprintVal = $("#Sprint").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Task/BindStoryList",            
        data: { projectTitle: selectedProjectVal, sprintTitle: selectedSprintVal },
        type: 'Get',
        success: function (result) { 
            $('#ddlStory').html(result);            },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("something seems wrong "+ err);
        }
    });
});
```

but now Story Dropdownlist is not displaying.

**MainPage.cshtml**

```
<table>
    @{
        if (ViewBag.ProjectList != null)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h4>SELECT PROJECT&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</h4>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("Project", new SelectList(ViewBag.ProjectList, "Value", "Text"), " -- Select -- ")
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        if (ViewBag.SprintList != null)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("PartialSprintDropDown", Model.AsEnumerable());
        }
        if (ViewBag.StoryList != null)
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("PartialStoryDropDown", Model.AsEnumerable());
        }
    }
</table>
```

**PartialSprintDropDown.cshtml**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h4>SELECT SPRINT</h4>
       </td>
       <td>
           &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;@Html.DropDownList("Sprint", new SelectList(ViewBag.SprintList, "Value", "Text"), " -- Select -- ")
       </td>
    </tr>      
</table>
<script src="~/Script/Task/IndexTask.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**PartialStoryDropDown.cshtml**

```
<div id="ddlStory">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4>SELECT STORY</h4>
           </td>
           <td>
               &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;@Html.DropDownList("Story", new SelectList(ViewBag.StoryList, "Value", "Text"), " -- Select -- ")
           </td>
        </tr>      
    </table>
</div>
<script src="~/Script/Task/IndexTask.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can anyone suggest me that why Story DropdownList is not displaying. Even when i m debbuging PartialStoryDropDown.cshtml, "ViewBag.StoryList" contains data as expected, but not showing on the page.

I m containing my data in Viewbag.SprintList and Viewbag.StoryList.
SprintDropdownlist is displaying.

How to resolve this ?

**BindSprintList()**

```
public ActionResult BindSprintList(string projectTitle)
        {
            try
            {
                string Owner = Session["UserName"].ToString();

                int? ProjectId = GetProjectID(projectTitle);

                var ddlSprint = new List<string>();

                List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

                var querySprint = (from sp in entities.Sprints
                                    where sp.Project_ID == ProjectId && sp.Sprint_Status != "Completed"
                                    select sp).ToList();

                foreach (var item in querySprint.ToList())
                {
                    SelectListItem li = new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = item.Sprint_Title,
                        Text = item.Sprint_Title
                    };
                    items.Add(li);
                }

                IEnumerable<SelectListItem> List = items;

                ViewBag.SprintList = new SelectList(List, "Value", "Text");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true);
                sw.WriteLine("Date    ::    " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                sw.WriteLine("Location ::  AgileMVC >> Controllers >> TaskController.cs >> public ActionResult BindSprintList(string projectTitle)");
                sw.WriteLine("Message ::    " + e.Message);
                sw.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                sw.Close();
            }

            return PartialView("PartialSprintDropDown", ViewBag.SprintList);
        }
```

**BindStoryList()**

```
public ActionResult BindStoryList(string projectTitle, string sprintTitle)
    {
        try
        {
            string Owner = Session["UserName"].ToString();

            int? ProjectId = GetProjectID(projectTitle);

            int? SprintId = GetSprintID(ProjectId, sprintTitle);

            var ddlStory = new List<string>();

            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

            var queryStory = (from st in entities.Stories
                                join spss in entities.SprintStories on st.Story_ID equals spss.Story_ID
                                where spss.Sprint_ID == SprintId && spss.Project_ID == ProjectId
                                select st).ToList();

            foreach (var item in queryStory.ToList())
            {
                SelectListItem li = new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = item.Story_Title,
                    Text = item.Story_Title
                };
                items.Add(li);
            }

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> List = items;

            ViewBag.StoryList = new SelectList(List, "Value", "Text");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, true);
            sw.WriteLine("Date    ::    " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            sw.WriteLine("Location ::  AgileMVC >> Controllers >> TaskController.cs >> public ActionResult BindStoryList()");
            sw.WriteLine("Message ::    " + e.Message);
            sw.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
            sw.Close();
        }

        return PartialView("PartialStoryDropDown", ViewBag.StoryList);
    }
```

Comment: Mind share your BindStoryList and BindSprintList action?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to show a `table` in a dropdown (guessing by `$('#ddlStory')` and your partial view's html.

Comment: Actually @Mrchief... i thought ishud put PartialStoryDropDown content in div tag wid id "ddlStory", thats why i m displaying that one...

Comment: So I guess a little more of your HTML would help. ddl - I assumed stands for dropdownlist!

Comment: Editing done @Mrchief...

Comment: I think I see your problem - **ddlStory** `div` comes as part of result. So when you say $('#ddlStory'), it doesn't do anything since its not on the page yet.

Comment: I think in your main page, you need to have a placeholder for `ddlStory` and replace that placeholder's html. Something like `$('#ddlStoryWrapper').html(result)` where `ddlStoryWrapper` is just an empty div on the page.

Comment: Thank u very much... @Mrchief... i was working on it since 2 days... nd i missed d point...

Comment: Gr8! Added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem - `ddlStory` div comes as part of result. So when you say `$('#ddlStory')`, it doesn't do anything since its not on the page yet.

I think in your main page, you need to have a placeholder for `ddlStory` and replace that placeholder's html. Something like `$('#ddlStoryWrapper').html(result)` where `ddlStoryWrapper` is just an empty div on the page.